# c++ error C2065: undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, class, identifier

----EDIT
Solution found, wrong namespaces for classes. This post may be as an example of that

I get this error and so I am confused what I do wrong exactly.
in some.cpp I declare:

**.cpp:**

```
#include "header1.hpp"
#include "header2.h"

using namespace wre;
namespace awq
{
  //somethings
  void function()
  {
      std::vector<classW>::iterator it1; //I mean class upr::classW
      std::map<int, classQ> map1; //I mean class pwe::classQ
      //iterations which don't work
  }
}
```

**header1.hpp**

```
namespace upr
{
class classW
   {
        //things
   }
}
```

**header2.h**

```
namespace wre
{
   class classQ
   {
      //things
   }
}
```

Why it doesn't see this classW? As consequence it1 is of unknown size ... so two stupid errors.

classQ - there is no problem.

What is the point here, anyone knows?
(I operate on various namespaces, I can add it to this post if this is necessary)

Comment: `Why it doesn't see this class?` The error does not say the class declaration was not found ; it says it is missing a default constructor. Did you define any custom constructors in classW ?

Comment: I am sorry, I pasted the wrong error as the title .. (is there option to change title? right one: error C2065: 'classW' : undeclared identifier

Comment: could be name lookup issue if classW/classQ is in another namespace. try to use full namespace for classW/classQ

Comment: If you can, please paste more of you code into the question, it will help us find what's wrong.

Comment: Please post a small example of *code* that repros the problem - I don't know what "I attach `#include "header1.hpp"` where `classW` is" means.

Comment: What is the compiler saying is undeclared? Have you `#include <vector>` and `#include <map>`?

Comment: Also, when asking about compiler/linker error messages, please post the complete line of the message.

Comment: thanks guys! when editing I found the mistake. it was that **std::vector<wre::classW>::iterator it1;** I forgot this **wre** namespace here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are doing is:

header1.h

```
namespace N{
  class classW{ };
}
```

header2.h

```
namespace M{
  class classQ{ };
}
```

some.cpp

```
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h
std::vector<classW>::iterator it1;
std::map<int, classQ> map1;
```

From here, you get undefined classW/classQ error, because compiler can't find classW/classQ from global namespace.

You could implement some.cpp like:

```
 #include "header1.h"
 #include "header2.h
 std::vector<N::classW> v1;
 std::vector<N::classW>::iterator it1;
 std::map<int, M::classQ> map1;
```

But this is all my guessing, need to see more code to see what's really happening in your code.

Comment: thanks, I found meanwhile while editing the mistake, exactly your guessing was right :)